# Parse.com PHP contains() method

Tags: php, parse-platform

I need a **Parse Query** method equivalent to SQL **LIKE** statement because I want to search for a substring in key's value. I looked at Parse docs and found that both **Javascript** and **iOS** SDKs of Parse has a method **contains** to look for substring in any key's value.

But no such method exists in Parse **PHP** SDK. Is there a way to achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no such function in Parse PHP API. So, I moved to Cloud Code and written a cloud function, because the Parse Javascript API has a **contains()** function to search for substrings.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Use startsWith to restrict to string values that start with a particular string. Similar to a MySQL LIKE operator, this is indexed so it is efficient for large datasets

```
// Finds barbecue sauces that start with "Big Daddy's".
$query = new ParseQuery("BarbecueSauce");
$query->startsWith("name", "Big Daddy's");
```

Comment: As the name of function explains itself that it will just return those results where the key's value starts with the search string. I want to search for substring anywhere in the key's value e.g. if the name field has a value "Big Daddy's" and I search for "Daddy", it should return the "Big Daddy's" in result as well.